# Circut to turn on a battery powered electric fence

Tags: arduino, switches, photoresistor

I want to be able to have a battery powered electric fence automatically turn on in the morning when it's day light, and power off when it gets dark. I don't seem to be able to find a product that does this - they all seem to be the exact opposite e.g. security lights turning once it gets dark, so I'm looking to build my own device to achieve this.

I've searched to see if there's a tutorial for this online, but I don't seem to be able to find one. I don't know if I'm not searching for the correct thing, or if I've just missed examples of this.

My thought was to use an Arduino, with photo-resistor cell to detect the light level, and use simple logic and a relay to turn on a the switch which then supplies power to the fence, and once it gets dark, break the switch to power off the fence. Is this the way to go, or is there a better way?

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this, or point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What drives the fence?  Do you have a battery feeding an inverter feeding a line voltage device or does the fence driver run directly off battery voltage?

Comment: It's straightforward to invert a signal that comes on at night to create one to turn on during the day.

Comment: If you found ready to use photo relay but wrong sequence you can invert logic with electromagnetic relay.

Comment: Reason I ask about the device driving the fence is that relays can waste rather a lot of power which matters when you're running off of batteries.  You should give the rated voltage and current of the device driving the fence and inverter as well if present.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be over-engineering things. Why not just use a £5 battery operated timer switch that will turn on and turn off at the appropriate times of the day: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.wish.com/product/5a60425664621a65793db829?hide_login_modal=true&from_ad=goog_shopping&_display_country_code=GB&_force_currency_code=GBP&pid=googleadwords_int&c=%7BcampaignId%7D&ad_cid=5a60425664621a65793db829&ad_cc=GB&ad_curr=GBP&ad_price=6.00&campaign_id=6493229882&exclude_install=true%7D&guest=true&gclid=Cj0KCQiAv6yCBhCLARIsABqJTjbH6R5wKHhVfl5Zed6MOHuQUnHfaZBlThT93uvn6QfkoIvneRFNjUwaApz5EALw_wcB&share=web). It'll be about as accurate as light sensing given that light sensing circuits can be affected by weather conditions.